# How to establish database relation in mysql and using eloquent with join

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, slim

I have three database tables

customers

```
customer_id(int), customer_name(varchar)
     1                  Business name
```

products

```
product_id(int), customer_id(int), product_name(varchar),  qty
    1                   1               Paper Glass        100
    2                   1               Pizza Boxex        100
```

delivery

```
delivery_id(int), customer_id(int), delivery_number(varchar)
     1                   1                 b-2321
```

delivered_items (this table contains more than one product for one delivery)

```
delivery_id, product_id, delivered_qty
      1           1           23
      1           2           68
```

I want to display a html table

```
Delivery Number, delivered products, Delivery Date etc...
```

My code is:

I retrieve deliveries for a customer(customer 1) with this

```
SELECT * FROM
delivery t1 
INNER JOIN 
customers t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
WHERE t1.customer_id = 1;
```

And I am trying the get delivered items with this code.

```
SELECT *
FROM
delivery_items t1 
INNER JOIN 
delivery t2 ON t1.delivery_id = t2.delivery_id
INNER JOIN
products t3 ON t1.product_id = t3.product_id
WHERE t1.delivery_id = 1;
```

My problem is that, how can I get delivery_id from previous results in php (see code below) and display delivered product in same view.

```
public function getCustomer($request, $response)
{
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $data['customer'] = Customer::where('customer_id', $id)->first();
    $data['delivery'] = $this->db->table('delivery')->join('customers', 'delivery.customer_id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')->select('delivery.delivery_id', 'delivery.delivery_number', 'delivery.status', 'delivery.created_at', 'customers.customer_id', 'customers.business_name')->where('customers.customer_id', $id)->get();

    if (!$data['customer']) {
        $this->flash->addMessage('error', 'Nothing delivered to this customer.');
        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('customers.customers'));          
    }

    return $this->view->render($response, 'customers/customer.twig', $data);
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve delivered products for a delivery. When I include delivered_items table into the join i get duplicated same delivery.

I hope I could explain...

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results as we need to know how to handle duplication ("ties").. Also you should provide the generated SQL from that PHPcode and you should also provide your attemped code..

Comment: But we need to have example data and expected results without we can only guess, because of the declarative nature of SQL..

Comment: @RaymondNijland let me try to update my question.

Comment: Generally you should fix data display issues in the controller/view render where you build a array/json where you "unduplicate" the SQL result to make it suitable for display.. A other option is using `GROUP_CONCAT(.. ORDER BY ...)` to merge the duplication for `delivered products, Delivery Date etc...` and use `explode()` .. That is about the best advice i can give you without a expected SQL results (ascii data table)/html table example as i don't know for sure how you want to display it as i am not going to assume (fill in the question marks/blanks) how you want it..